# Can Fleiss' Kappa test the agreement of three different parameters?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, categorical-data, cohens-kappa

I have a question about statistics. I have a question about the kappa coefficient. I think this coefficient is used for rater reliability.
However, is it possible to test the consistency change of two different parameters?
For example, I want to test whether is a consistent change in performance A(improvement/decline) and performance B (improvement/decline) in a binomial manner.

I felt that few papers use the consistency of two different parameters.

However, we think it is beneficial.
I can also test the relationship between the three parameters by using the Fleiss' Kappa. Is it possible to use it for purposes other than rater reliability?

I would like to know if it is possible and if you have any documentation related to this point.

Comment: It is unclear to me what your question is but your first one might be answered by using McNemar's test.

Comment: Thank you. I would like to verify the congruency of the + and - of the two items (or three).

Comment: e.g.,)For the two items, they are as follows

Improvement in two items, A and B = 18 people
Decline in two items (A and B) = 2 people
A improved, B decreased = 3 people
A declines, B improves = 2 people

We want to show that A and B are changing at the same time.

Comment: Have a look at McNemar's test and see if it answers what you want. I suspect it does but I am not sure.

Comment: Thanks. I checked it. But in my case, two parameters do not unpaired each other, so it cannot be applied successfully.